# How to download files from Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, sharepoint-online

I have a requirement to download files (Excel) from Sharepoint online to local directory using "SSIS". Please advise on the options available.

I am new to SSIS

Answer (score 1):

you cannot connect to sharepoint online site using SSIS.
you should try using SharePoint CSOM or SharePoint JSOM to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Get SharePoint online SDK from

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM/

Then, you could use CSOM to access SharePoint.

https://salvoz.com/posts/2014-05-23-connect-to-sharepoint-online-list-via-csom-in-ssis.html

Sample code to access SharePoint file by CSOM.

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = GetContextObject()) 
            { 

                Web web = clientContext.Web; 
                clientContext.Load(web, website => website.ServerRelativeUrl); 
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
                Regex regex = new Regex(SiteUrl, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
                string strSiteRelavtiveURL = regex.Replace(FileUrl, string.Empty); 
                string strServerRelativeURL = CombineUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl, strSiteRelavtiveURL); 

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File oFile = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(strServerRelativeURL); 
                clientContext.Load(oFile); 
                ClientResult<Stream> stream = oFile.OpenBinaryStream(); 
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
                return this.ReadFully(stream.Value); 
            }
```

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/file-from-SharePoint-Online-cc418dba

Comment: Thanks for the response. What are the options available for Sharepoint On premise? I don't see any sharepoint connectors available out of the box for SSIS.